# debugging functions in the clojurescript repl

Tags: clojurescript

Does anybody know a good way to debug functions in the clojureScript REPL?

The default, behavior is that the generated JS code of the function is printed.

```
midi.lib=> (defn f [] (println "hello"))
#'midi.lib/f
midi.lib=> f
#object[midi$lib$f "function midi$lib$f(){
return cljs.core.println.call(null,"hello");
}"]
```

With longer functions this gets annoying. For many debugging cases, simply the name of the function would be sufficient..

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no support for controlling how function values print in ClojureScript.

But, if you are OK with extending the JavaScript function type, you can evaluate the following in a REPL

```
(extend-type js/Function
  IPrintWithWriter
  (-pr-writer [obj writer _]
    (let [name (.-name obj)
          name (if (empty? name)
                 "Function"
                 name)]
      (write-all writer "#object[" name "]"))))
```

and then your example function value would print as `#object[midi$lib$f]`.

Comment: looks good, I'll try it later. Would there be a way to keep it out of my code? or: somehow have it only in development code and not in production..

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Figwheel REPL, it doesn't print out the generated JS, and behaves similarly to a Clojure REPL.

Comment: oh, I'm using the figwheel REPL. but it does behave as described. in yours it doesn't?